# I Got Indentation Error. How to Fix it......?

Tags: django, python-3.x

After running server, it gives error for unexpected indentaion....!!!!
What should i do....????

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Add traceback of error

Comment: Unless you're mixing tabs and spaces and that's causing weird behaviour, I don't think the problem is with this code. But ya, include the full error in the question so we know for sure.

Comment: if indentations look good but you get error then you may mix spaces and tabs (which look the same but Python threads them different). Some editors have function "convert spaces to tabs" or "convert tabs to spaces". Editors may have also option to convert tabs automatically when you save file - it resolves all problems with tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you have indentation problems you can install this library. Here is an example.:

```
pip install autopep8
```

sample.py

```
import os, sys

#Listing directories
os.system('ls -lah')
```

shell:

```
autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive sample.py
```

output:

```
import os
import sys

# Listing directories
os.system('ls -lah')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
## This the Code of view.py ##



 from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Post

    posts=[

        {
            'author':'Sohaib',
            'title':'Blog Post 1',
            'content':'First post content',
            'date_posted':'28 March,2019',
        },
        {
            'author':'Shafiq',
            'title':'Blog Post 2',
            'content':'Second post content',
            'date_posted':'29 March,2019',
        }

    ]

    def home(request):
        context={
            'posts':Post.objects.all()
        }
        return render(request,'blog/home.html',context)

    def about(request):
        return render(request,'blog/about.html',{'title':'About'})
```

Comment: This is the question, not the answer, don't use the answer to update your question, just update your question. Delete this please.